# Understanding the Vector Space of Polynomials of a Certain Type of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ complex diagonal matrix with exactly three distint entries on its diagonal.

(1) What is the dimension of the vector space of polynomials of $A$?

(2) What is the dimension of the vector space of $4 \times 4$ complex matrices that commute with $A$?

(3) If $B$ is a $4 \times 4$ complex diagonal matrix with exactly three distinct entries on its diagonal, is it similar to a polynomial of $A$?

I am looking for explainations more so than the actual answers.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with Jordan canonical form and with minimal polynomials?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have some familarity with Jordan canonical form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make writing things easier, I will specifically consider the case where the repeated eigenvalue comes first.  That is, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_1 \\ && \lambda_2 \\ &&& \lambda_3} = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 I_{2}\\ & \lambda_2 \\ && \lambda_3}
$$
where $I_2$ denotes a size $2$ identity matrix.

**Hint for 1:** Note that for any polynomial $p$,
$$
p(A) = \pmatrix{p(\lambda_1)I_{2} \\ & p(\lambda_2) \\ && p(\lambda_3)}
$$

**Hint for 2:** Verify that any block matrix of the form
$$
B = \pmatrix{B_1\\ & b_2 \\ && b_3}
$$
will commute with $A$, where $B_1$ can be any $2 \times 2$ matrix and the $b_i$ are scalars. Note too that these are the only matrices that commute with $A$.

**Hint for 3:** Every polynomial of $A$ is diagonal (and therefore diagonalizable).  However, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{\lambda_1&1 \\ & \lambda_1 \\ && \lambda_2 \\ &&& \lambda_3}
$$
is neither diagonal nor diagonalizable.